# How to map a Java class property that is an object to a single JPA table column?

Tags: java, object, jpa

I have a Sprint Boot web service that is using JPA to map to an underlying SQL database.

One of the domain classes has a property that is a complex Java object  that I do not want to persist with the normal mapped/joined tables. Instead I want to map this Java object to a single column in the main table, and ideally store the data in a JSON format in a string column.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jpa's [AttributeConverter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html):

```
@Converter
public class MyObjectConverter implements AttributeConverter<MyObject, String> {
 @Override
 public String convertToDatabaseColumn(MyObject myObject) {
    //convert myobject to json: for instance use ObjectMapper from Jackson
    if( myObject == null )
        return null;

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(myObject );
 }

 @Override
 public MyObject convertToEntityAttribute(String myObjectString) {
    // convert myObjectString back to object
    if( myObjectString== null )
        return null;

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return mapper.readValue(myObjectString, MyObject.class);
 }  
}
```

and use it in your entity as..

```
@Column
@Converter(converter = MyObjectConverter.class)
MyObject myObject;
```

Comment: Many thanks!  The write is working, but when I try to read the parent object the 'MyObject' property is coming back as null.  Is 'fetch' relevant here?

Comment: Found the issue.  I'm using Java8 time 'Instant' and this seems not to be supported by the reading stream. Any suggestions?

Comment: Fixed the 'Instant problem... mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);

Comment: Glad it helped :)